# Xamarin Froms Entry Custom Control does not work

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, bindableproperty

I'm trying to make a custom control to use it in multiple places.
the thing is it works fine with the label but when it comes to entry it won't even run and it gives me

```
No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "EntryText"
```

here is my custom control Xaml:

<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"

```
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="MyLabel" />
            <Entry x:Name="MyEntry" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

and its code behind

```
   public partial class MyCustomControl : ContentView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty LabelTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(LabelText),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MyCustomControl),
            propertyChanged: LabelTextPropertyChanged);

        private static void LabelTextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = (MyCustomControl)bindable;
            control.MyLabel.Text = newValue?.ToString();
            Debug.WriteLine("LabelTextPropertyChanged: " + control.MyEntry);
            Debug.WriteLine("LabelTextPropertyChanged: new value" + newValue);
        }

        public string LabelText 
        {
            get => base.GetValue(LabelTextProperty)?.ToString();
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value);
            }
        }


        public static  BindableProperty EntryBindableProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(EntryText),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MyCustomControl),
            propertyChanged:EntryBindablePropertyChanged
            );

        private static void EntryBindablePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = (MyCustomControl)bindable;
            Debug.WriteLine("EntryBindablePropertyChanged: " + control.MyEntry);
            Debug.WriteLine("EntryBindablePropertyChanged: new value" + newValue);
        }

        public string EntryText
        {
            get => base.GetValue(EntryBindableProperty)?.ToString();
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(EntryBindableProperty, value);
            }
        }
        public MyCustomControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

and its Usage

```
<StackLayout>
        <local:MyCustomControl 
            LabelText="{Binding BindingLabel}" 
            EntryText="{Binding BindingEntry}"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

NOTE:
I tried to remove the

```
 </ContentView.Content>
```

from my xaml because i've seen some example like that,
and also i've tried to set binding in the code behind constructor

```
 public MyCustomControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding(nameof(EntryText) , source: this));
        }
```

but neither did work for the entry .
so how can i resolve this and does it make any additional setting if i want to bind the value to a view model.
thanks in advance.

**Update:**
@Jessie Zhang -MSFT
thanks for your help I really appreciate it,
however I discovered a bug in MyCustomControl code => EntryTextProperty
is that i have to declare the defaultBindingMode to be able to get the data passed to a ViewModel Property.
so i changed the BindableProperty code to:

```
public static  BindableProperty EntryTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(EntryText),
            typeof(string),
            typeof(MyCustomControl),
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWayToSource,
            propertyChanged:EntryBindablePropertyChanged
            );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't bind the `Entry.Text` and `EntryText` property in `MyCustomControl.xaml`:

Please refer the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CardViewDemo.Controls.MyCustomControl"
             
             x:Name="this"
             >
  <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference this}">
            <Label x:Name="MyLabel" Text="{Binding LabelText}" />
            <Entry x:Name="MyEntry" Text="{ Binding EntryText}"  />
        </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

And I used the following code to did a test, it works properly.

```
        <local:MyCustomControl 
        LabelText="test1" 
        EntryText="test2"/>
```

**Update:**

From document [Create a property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#create-a-property),we know that:

> The naming convention for bindable properties is that the bindable
> property identifier must match the property name specified in the
> Create method, with "Property" appended to it.

So, you can change your code `EntryBindableProperty`   to `EntryTextProperty`, just as follows:

```
    public static readonly  BindableProperty EntryTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(EntryText), typeof(string),typeof(MyCustomControl),string.Empty, BindingMode.TwoWay, null, EntryBindablePropertyChanged);

    public string EntryText
    {
        get => base.GetValue(EntryTextProperty)?.ToString();
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(EntryTextProperty, value);
        }

    }
```

And the xaml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CardViewDemo.Controls.MyCustomControl"
             
             x:Name="template"
             >
  <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout >
            <Label x:Name="MyLabel"  Text="{Binding  Source={x:Reference template},Path=LabelText}"/>       

            <Entry x:Name="MyEntry"  Text="{Binding EntryText, Source={x:Reference template}}"  >
            </Entry>
       
        </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast reply , however i tried your code and it worked but when i try to bind those texts to the code behind i get the same error.

<local:MyCustomControl 
            LabelText="{Binding BindingLabel}" 
            EntryText="{Binding BindingEntry}"/>

Comment: Hi  @AbanoubRefaat,  I have updated my answer, you can check the updated part.